# mysqli query returns 0 results despite information in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in the process of making a login screen so once the session has been set a person can access various pages on my site.

It seems, however, that when I send the username and password to be compared with what I have in the MySQL database the results come back empty.

**MySQL table:**

```
Id, Username, Password, Email, group
1,  bunbun, hashedpassword, example@email.com, admin
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
include_once("functions/con-open.php");

if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $name = $_POST['username'];

    //$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
}

function LOGIN($Name, $Password)
{
    $conn = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

    if ($conn->connect_errno) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }   

    if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Username='$Name'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
    {
        printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
        echo "<br>Name  Dump<br>";
        var_dump($Name);
        echo "<br>Password  Dump <br>"; 
        var_dump($Password);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump( $result);
        $result->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo"no details returned <br>";
        var_dump( $result);
        $result->close();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>


<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login-form">
Email: <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    LOGIN($NAME, $PASSWORD); 
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**The result is**

```
    Select returned 0 rows.
This is what I have typed in username field: 
This is what I have typed in password field:
Name from DB:
Password from DB:

object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? 
The column for my hash is Vchar(255) I gave it enough room from the beginning.

Update! This maybe more serious, I have changed the code above to reflect the excellent answer from maytham. however it is still returning 0 results
I took the liberty of adding within the loop, `if (isset($_POST['username']))`

```
echo "This is what the value name is: ".$name."<br>";
```

and the same just before i call LOGIN($name, password); to see if $name is set, it is.
however between the function being called and $Name being used in the sql query the value is empty. Not sure why that would be I'll have to debug my php installation to see if there is any bugs.

Comment: Your code suggests that there are no results when the query _fails_, but returning an empty result set is not a failure. If your call to MySQL is _failing_ you should check `$conn->error` to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, escape `$Name` before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have observed and fix it for you.

Follow the steps and it should works:

**Step A**

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Username='$Name'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
```

To

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Username = '$Name'"))
```

**Step B**

The code presented in the question, the function LOGIN need to end with `}`

```
function LOGIN($Name, $Password)
```

**Step C (Optional)**

When I test I have changed password to plain text to be sure every thing is working, but it is up to you.

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

**Step D**

At the beginning of the code I will put `if statement`

```
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    // disable for testing
    //$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

**Step E (Optional)**

I suggest you change all variables like `$USERNAME` to `$username`

**Step F**

Try to protect your inputs from SQL injection by adding `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

- thank to user @ibu for noticing that

**Finally**
**Here is the full workable code with my modification:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    //$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
}
function LOGIN($Name, $Password)
{
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    if ($conn->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    }

    if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Username = '$Name'"))
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
        echo "<br />";
        echo "This is what I have typed in username field: " . $Name;
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<b>Name from DB: </b>" . $row['Username'] . "<br />";
        echo "<b>Password from DB: </b>" . $row['Password'] . "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        var_dump($result);
        $result->close();
    } else
    {
        echo "no details returned <br>";
        var_dump($result);
        $result->close();
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login-form">
    Email: <input type="text" name="username"/><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    LOGIN($name, $password);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is a test shot from my screen:**
[image]

**Note:** When all this mentioned, this does not mean the code or what is presented is a good or perfect solution. There is a lot you have to think about when building a login mechanism. The code is also vulnerable for SQL injection you need and have to do a lot work. I encourage you to look at:

Link1: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Link2: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Link3: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: if the user send `' or 1 --` with an `union select clause` in the email field, he can find the list of all the usernames and passwords on the database. Also known as SQL injection. Please use at least mysqli_real_escape_string();

Comment: I have edit it, therefore I suggested to check OWASP link. thanks for the tips

Comment: Is there an alternative to mysql_real_escape string? it throws an access denied for user error, I am using PDO to send my sql queries, so it seems thats why the error has come up

Comment: Nevermind I have figured it out :-) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have either edited data or need a trim () for invisible chars.

```
string(13) "bunbun"
```

That's not 13 chars in length

There's no reason as it currently stands that the query should dump like it is.

As others have noted. Be aware if SQL injection too